# What happens if the UK government refuses to function or carry out its duties?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, parliament

The timeline of Brexit in recent weeks has involved an attempt to call an early general election by the government, which failed to meet the required two thirds majority of the entire house as set out in the Fixed Term Parliaments Act, and has resulted in rumours that the government may call a vote of no confidence in itself (which has a lower threshold than the first attempt as it is set at a simple majority).

There have also been rumours that the government may attempt to call an election by way of passing a bill, which bypasses the Fixed Term Parliaments Act, but can result in the bill being amended by the opposition.

Given that the opposition has taken the stance that it will oppose any calls for an early election, and given that the current government has lost its voting majority in the last week, it is unlikely that the government will succeed in causing an early election to be held.

***However, what laws or rules are in place and enforceable to ensure that the government cannot simply sit back, sulk and refuse to carry out any business (other than perhaps opposing bills in Parliament that are designed to force the government to act)?***

Comment: Parliament will be prorogued in less than a week, and I can't imagine much of consequence will happen in that week *besides* maybe calling an election somehow. If the government did as you suggest, I imagine Corbyn would be thrilled at the campaign material that Boris would be giving him for free.

Comment: When you refer to carrying out business, are you referring to business in Parliament, or are you referring to something else specifically?

Comment: @JoeC I’m referring to everything involved in being the government, other than opposing acts intended to force them into action.  Bringing pointless bills etc is fine.

Comment: It's not uncommon for countries to function without a government.  In 2010/11, Belgium was without a government for 589 days  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010%E2%80%9311_Belgian_government_formation

Comment: I feel as if the current deadlock is because ministers are second guessing what the people meant by the referendum, so can be unblocked by a second referendum now that the options are clear, however it doesn't look as if that is going to happen.  There is a petition for such a referendum but it has only 60 votes, so basically it has no support: https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/253709 .

Comment: In theory, the Queen can dismiss a Prime Minister (and their government) if she wishes. This power hasn't been used since 1834, but if the government refused to function as a government, she may well decide to get involved. After the prorogation on August 28th was ruled unlawful, there were reports that the Queen had sought legal advice on whether she could dismiss Boris Johnson, and how to do so, so while she tries to stay out of politics, it seems that she's not afraid to get involved if she feels that it would be in the country's best interests.

Answer (score 2):

Have a vote of no confidence. If the government manages to win that, well then, their sulking is with parliments blessing. If they lose, parliment can appoint a new government (simplified version of the process, but essentially what occurs), or if it cannot agree to do so, will dissolve itself and call fresh elections

Answer (score 1):

There are two main options.

1. Motion of no confidence in the government, allowing an alternative government (that commands a majority) to take over. If no alternative is viable then a General Election is automatically triggered.
2. Legal action to force the government to comply. Refusing to comply with the law could expose government ministers, particularly the Prime Minister as they are the ultimate authority, to charges of contempt of court and ministerial misconduct. Both carry jail time, the latter a maximum of life in prison.